# Show the same data retrieved by the AJAX call after the user returns to the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get URL of this form and display the results with AJAX, all works fine, but as soon as i visit a link of one the results achieved, I would lose all the data retrieved earlier during the AJAX call. What I want is, when the user presses the back button on the browser, they would be returned to the same page with the same data retrieved from AJAX call before leaving the page. I am building an e-commerce site.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form").change(function(){
        var form=$("#form").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "get.php",
                data: form,
                success: function(html) {
                    $("#pagination").fadeOut(0).html(html).fadeIn(300);
                }
            });
        return false;
        });
    });
```

After back button is pressed:

I have this url: search.php
Though I will need to achieve: search.php?brand=Honda&model=etc

Comment: `#form` is a form id or any button id?

Comment: @user2765552 I think you should also post html code.

Comment: @AG21 is the form id

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulating the browser history to do that :

```
if (typeof (history.pushState) != "undefined") {
    var obj = { Title: title, Url: url };
    history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
} else {
    alert("Browser does not support HTML5.");
}
```

Construct your url in the Object :

```
var obj = { Title: 'Title of my page', Url: 'search.php?brand='+form.brand+'&model='+form.model };
```

You have to place this code in your success callback function.

Comment: As soon as I add this two pieces of code, the script stop working

Comment: What error did you get in your console ?
Did you replace form.model and form.brand by the appropriate name retrive from your form ?

Comment: Yes i replace but when I add var obj = {...} and I create and alert its said form.brand undefined and if i add the if (typeof (history) != "undefined") the script stop working... I try inside my success callback and out too!